# Socket Packet Post Data Truncated

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, packet

I am working with c++ socket programming, where I am posting a long string to a webpage to be processed. The program runs ok, however, the data that I am sending is truncated. So the webpage could not process the data successfully.

```
#MAXLINE[4096]

ssize_t myclass::send_data(const char *host,const char *page,const char *poststr)
{
   char sendline[MAXLINE+1], recvlin[MAXLINE+1];
   size_t n;
   int c_length = strlen(poststr);
   snprintf(sendline,MAXSUB ,
           "POST %s HTTP/1.0\r\n"
           "HOST: %s\r\n"
           "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
           "Content-length: %d\r\n\r\n"
           "%s", page, host, c_length, poststr);
   int line_length = sizeof(sendline);

   int sig_status = send(sock, sendline, line_length,0);


   if (sig_status < 0){
     signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_IGN);
   }
  return n;
}
```

How can I not truncated the data that I am sending?

Comment: `int line_length = sizeof(sendline);` can be `int line_length = strlen(sendline);` You don't need to send 4096 bytes, just send the minimum required data. On the other hand, TCP is reliable, if data is truncated maybe the problem is in the conection timeout, if you can reduce data length you can solve the problem.

Comment: @eferion I don't think it is a connection timeout issue. Because I am getting a response back from the server. Just not the right response. Do you know if it is possible to untruncated the data, without reducing the data length?

Comment: what is the value of `MAXSUB`?? if it is lower than data length, it will be truncated.

Comment: @eferion It was set to 200, I bumped it up. It works now! Thanks!